# Paginacion JqGrid Virtual Scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

tengo el siguiente problema. Estoy usando jqGrid con jquery con la siguiente configuración y trato de implementar el virtual scroll **scroll: 1**.

```
var jqGridOptions = { url:'/index.php/solicitudes/DataSolicitudes',
  mtype : "post", 
  datatype: "json",
  colNames:['Id Solicitud','Contenido','Medio Respuesta','Ingreso','Fecha límite','Fecha Límite Completar','Estatus','Id_Estatus','Fecha Venc. Prorroga',"Nombre Unidad"],
  colModel:[
     {name:'id_solicitud',index:'id_solicitud', width: 80},
     {name:'contenido',index:'contenido', width: 400},        
     {name:'id_medio_respuesta',index:'id_medio_respuesta', width:120 },                              
     {name:'fecha_ingreso',index:'fecha_ingreso', width:90 },
     {name:'fecha_limite_entrega',index:'fecha_limite_entrega', width:90 },                          
     {name:'fecha_limite_completar',index:'fecha_limite_completar', width:150 },  
     {name:'id_estatus',index:'id_estatus', width:90 },         
     {name:'id_estatus2',index:'id_estatus2', width:20 },
     {name:'fecha_prorroga',index:'fecha_prorroga', width:140 },                           
     {name:'nombre_unidad_enlace',index:'nombre_unidad_enlace', width:250 }
  ],
  rowNum:50,
  autowidth: true,
  height:450,
  rowList:[50,100,200],
  pager: '#pagerSolicitudes',
  sortname: 'id_solicitud',
  viewrecords: true,
  sortorder: "desc",
  toolbar: [true,"top"],
  multiselect: false,
  shrinkToFit: false,
  gridview:true,
  scroll: 1,
  caption:"Solicitudes"
  };

 $solicitudes.jqGrid(jqGridOptions);
```

El problema es que cuando se hace el scroll hacia abajo, la pagina siguiente es 4 y no 2, la que sigue es 8 y no 3. He leido y entiendo que es un bug de la propia libreria, pero ¿Hay alguna solucion para esto?, ya baje la ultima version de la libreria la 5.1.0, pero me sigue sin funcionar.

Del lado del servidor uso php.